# Is the Electric Potential infinite above a surface with a charge density $\cos(x+y)^2$ everywhere on the $x$-$y$ plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

Suppose we have a charge density $\sigma (x,y) = \cos(x+y)^2$ everywhere on the x-y plane. The distribution of charges should look like constant stripes running along the $\vec{x}-\vec{y}$ direction, but alternating in density from $0<z<1$ (black and yellow respectively) in a manner shown in the contour plot below.

[image]

Now, the potential above a charged infinite plane with constant density is indeed infinite, as explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/208482/361084) in a question about the subject matter. The user who answered the question, Brian Moths, writes,

> This infinity was possible because we had infinitely much Q. Notice
> the electric field still works out because the infinite part does not
> have a spatial gradient.

In other words, the potential satisfies Laplace's Equation:

$$\nabla^2\Phi=0$$

Then, in the case that I've proposed, would the potential above the plane be infinite? As a general solution, I start with:

$$\Phi(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\sigma(x,y)f(z)$$ where $\sigma(x,y)=cos(x+y)^2$ and $f(z)$ is some function that depends on $z$.

If $\Phi\rightarrow 0$ as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ (if the potential is zero above the plane). Then the $z$ function can just be $f(z)=e^{-|z|}$.

If $\Phi\rightarrow\infty$ as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, then the $z$ function can be anything from $f(z)=e^{|z|}$ to one that produces an infinity.

Consider the argument that was made for the case for an infinite plane with uniform charge density where there is a net amount of charge $Q$. Now, take a look at the contour plot that I attached above. Suppose I zoom away from the plane to infinity, i.e., $|z|\rightarrow\infty$. Regardless, there is indeed some net charge $Q$ on the plane. But can the density now be considered constant across the plane when we zoom away to infinity?

If so, will the crests (positive charge density) or troughs (zero charge density) dominate? The latter case should not make physical sense since we've established that there is a net charge $Q$. Then, the solution to the problem should be similar in nature to the one proposed for the potential above a uniformly charged infinite plane.

Do you agree with this *general* solution for the potential? How would you approach finding an *exact* solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could first rotate your system by $45^\circ$: $x'={1\over\sqrt 2}(x+y)$, $x'={1\over\sqrt 2}(x-y)$. The charge density on the plane becomes simpler: $\sigma=\sigma_0\cos^2\sqrt 2x$ (I have omitted the prime on $x$ but it is the rotated coordinate). It involves only the (new) $x$ coordinate so that the charge distribution is invariant under a translation along the $y$ axis. As consequence, the electric potential does not depend on the $y$ coordinate. Your are left with $\Phi=\Phi(x,z)$, i.e. a 2D problem. Instead of solving Laplace equation, you can also try to integrate the charge distribution
$$\Phi(x,z)={\sigma_0\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int   {\cos^2\sqrt 2x'\over\sqrt{(x-x')^2+y'^2+z^2}}dx'dy'$$
As pointed out by @Puk, the integral does not converge. It is also the case for the infinite plane with a uniform charge density. However, the integral for the electric field
$$\vec E(x,y,z)={\sigma_0\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int{\cos^2\sqrt 2x'\over[(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z^2]^{3/2}}\pmatrix{x-x'\cr y-y' \cr z-z'}dx'dy'$$
should converge.

Comment: This integral does not converge, hence the "infinite potential" issue.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer.

Comment: In your integral for $\vec{E}(x,y,z)$ you should put $z^\prime =0$.

Comment: Oups! Thanks a lot!